# WPF binding label content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Have a trouble with binding to label content

I have special custom TabControl in page. Bind SelectedTab property from page viewmodel to controlview model to get actualSelectedTab

```
public int SelectedTab
    {
        get { return _selectedTab; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedTab, value);
        }
    }
```

For example, my tab control has 3 tabs; When tab one is selected - Selected Tab value is 0, etc.

But I need to show what current tab is selected in mainPage like 1/3 - 2/3 - 3/3

My final result must be like:

Selected Tab 1/3 ... 3/3

```
<Label
                                     Margin="5 0 28 0"  
           VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            TextElement.FontSize="12"
            TextElement.FontWeight="Bold"
            TextElement.Foreground="White" 
            VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
            Content="{Binding SelectedTab, Mode=OneWay}">


                                   </Label>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are not updating the UI in your property. You have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your ViewModel like this

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
    }

    public int SelectedTab
    {
        get { return _selectedTab; }
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _selectedTab, value);
            OnPropertyChanged("SelectedTab");
        }
    }
}
```

You're `Label` should show now the `SelectedTab` (0, 1, 2, etc.). When you want do display e.g. 1/3 you should do this with an `IValueConverter`.

You need to implement `IValueConverter`

```
public class MyConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var tabIndex = int.Parse(value.ToString());
        return tabIndex + 1;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, 
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //don't needed
    }
}
```

And in your xaml change your binding like
 `Content="{Binding SelectedTab, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}, Mode=OneWay}`

And in `Window` or `UserControl` add this in your resources to access the converter

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MyConverter x:Key="MyConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: My ViewModel is Child of MainViewModel that implement's INotiifyPropetryChanged, and yes 0,1,2 works perfect.
Can you give me an example of using IValueConverter, maybe it is what I need?

Comment: Updated my answer